# Understanding typedef with struct

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I am getting a hard time understanding this sample of code:

```
typedef struct node
{
        int data;
        struct node * next;
} node;

typedef node * nodepointer;
```

So, we are building the struct node using typedef... I assume we are doing this in order to initialize the struct without the "struct" keyword being necessary.

I want to ask why in the struct definition we used the name "node" **twice** (at start and end).

Secondly what `typedef node * nodepointer;` points to. Is it necessary to use typedef in this case? Is this expression `node * nodepointer;` not equal?

Comment: @artm nope, this is asking a bit more than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is that you are doing two things at once: declaring struct type and typedefing that struct to a name.

For `typedef` the syntax is

```
typedef <some type> name;
```

where some type may be a simple type, like `int`, `long`, etc. or a complex one like `struct foo`, and this regardless of wether `struct foo` has been declared before or it's being declared at that very point.

So

```
typedef struct foo { int bar; } foo;
```

Corresponds to

```
typedef <some type> name;
```

where `<some type>` is `struct foo { int bar; }` and `name` is `foo`

As to the second question,

In this case `<some type>` is `node *` and `name` is `nodepointer`, so

```
typedef node * nodepointer;
```

is typedefing a `nodepointer` as a pointer to a `node` (which you have typedefd just before to be a `struct node { ... }`)

Answer (score 5):

First off, let's be clear here: a `typedef` isn't a declaration of a variable. It simply aliases a new type *name* to an existing type specifier.

```
typedef <type specifier> new_type_name;
```

---

So what's going on here can certainly be deceiving to the untrained eye.

`struct node` itself is a `struct` called `node` with the two properties `int data` and a `struct node *next`.

I'll go more into `next` in a moment, but for now this is simple enough.

Then, the surrounding `typedef` takes that struct and gives it the name `node`. Why is this, you might ask?

This is due to the fact that in C (unlike C++) using structs by their [tag name](http://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/programming-pointers/4024450/Tag-vs-Type-Names) requires prefixing the type with `struct`.

```
struct Foo {
    // ...
};

Foo bar; // ERROR
struct Foo bar; // OK
```

Using a typedef, we alias the struct with a *typename*, called `node`. This example should make it a bit more clear.

```
typedef struct Foo {
    // ...
} FooType;

Foo bar; // ERROR
struct Foo bar; // OK

FooType bar; // OK
struct FooType bar; // ERROR
```

Keep in mind you can define structs without tags, and thus `typedef` them.

```
typedef struct {
    // ...
} FooType;

FooType bar; // OK
```

Though I'll explain why you *can't* do this in your example.

The property `struct node *next` in your example is an [incomplete type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/200xfxh6.aspx). Incomplete types, simply put, are types that have been *declared* (given a name and a type, i.e. `struct node;`), but not *defined* (given a 'body', i.e. `struct node { int foo; };`).

Incomplete types *cannot* be used until they are defined, *unless you're pointing to them*.

```
struct Foo;

struct Foo bar; // ERROR: Foo is not defined.
struct Foo *bar; // OK - it's just a pointer. We know the size of a pointer.

struct Foo {
    // ...
};

struct Foo bar; // OK - it's defined now.
```

So by the type `struct node *next` is declared, we already have the *declaration* of `struct node` but not the *definition*, which makes a pointer to `struct node` possible.

You can also infer, too, that using `struct node` directly would **not** work:

```
struct node {
    struct node next; // ERROR - `struct node` becomes infinitely big
    struct node *next; // OK - a pointer is usually 4/8 bytes (we at least know its size at this point)
};
```

---

To answer your last three questions:

> What [does] `typedef node * nodepointer;` [point] to[?]

Nothing. It's just an *alias* (a label, or a 'nickname') to another type. It simply says that the type `nodepointer` is really a `node *`.

This also means anything that requires a `node *` can thus use a `nodepointer`, and vice versa.

> Is it necessary to use `typedef` in this case?

Not necessary, no. You could just as well use `node *` everywhere instead of `nodepointer`. Most coding standards frown upon `typedef`ing types to their pointer types (like your example) because it adds confusion to the code base (as you have demonstrated by this very question! :))

> Is [the] expression `node * nodepointer;` not equal?

Nope. Again, remember `typedef` simply specifies another way to reference the same type. It doesn't actually *create* any memory, rather gives a new name to an existing type.

Answer (score 3):

This struct is self referential which means it contains a pointer to itself.

if you don't use tag `node`, How will you specify pointer type later. Hence first `node` is required

```
struct node {
    struct node *ptr;    
};
// you can do this way too
typdef struct node node;
```

The last `node` is required for completing the `typedef`.

By `typedef node * nodepointer;`, Now you can use `nodepointer` to mean `node*`. Wherever `node*` occurs, you can simply replace with `nodepointer`

> Is it necessary to use typedef in this case?

It is upto you,

> Is this expression node * nodepointer; not equal?

No, this only declares `nodepointer` to be **pointer variable** whereas `typedef` creates **alias of type**, `node *` by the name `nodepointer`.

Comment: Thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct node
    int data;
    struct node * next;
} node;
```

The `node` in the first line is the **tag** of the structure.

The `node` in the last line is the name of the type.

These two do not have to be identical.

If you want them to be different the code will be as follows.

```
typedef struct helloNode
    int data;
    struct helloNode * next;
} node;
```

The name of the type is `node`. The name of the structure is `helloNode`

For a more technical explanation, these two `nodes` are in different **namespaces**. and can have different values.

From section 6.3 of http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf

> If more than one declaration of a particular identifier is visible at any point in a
>   translation unit, the syntactic context disambiguates uses that refer to different entities.
>   Thus, there are separate name spaces for various categories of identifiers, as follows:
>
> — label names (disambiguated by the syntax of the label declaration and use);
>
> — the tags of structures, unions, and enumerations (disambiguated by following any32)
>   of the keywords struct, union, or enum);
>
> — the members of structures or unions; each structure or union has a separate name
>   space for its members (disambiguated by the type of the expression used to access the
>   member via the . or -> operator);
>
> — all other identifiers, called ordinary identifiers (declared in ordinary declarators or as
>   enumeration constants).

Comment: Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Daleisha said correctly that you need the struct tag in order to declare the pointer `next` which points to just these structures. You cannot write that type name down before it is introduced. Another possibility is to forward-declare the struct:

```
struct node;
typedef struct node node;

struct node
{
    node *next;
    int i;
};
```

But that introduces rather more mentionings of one `node`  or another.

As a side effect, introducing the struct tag "node" makes it possible to still write the normal `struct node`, which the typedef alone would not make possible.

The second typedef is also still a typedef, it doesn't introduce a variable but a type name. After all the declarations in your source snippet you can say

```
struct node *np1;
node *np1;
nodepointer np1;
```

These are all equivalent.

The co-existence of the two type names `node` and `struct node`  is possible because "struct tags" (like the "node" in "struct node"), as they are called, are held separately from other names and can therefore be used to name something else, additionally, without collision. To typedef a struct so that the new type has the name of the struct tag is a common example, but the name "node" could be used for anything else instead (an int variable, whatever).

Comment: Actually the reason why `struct node` still has its tag in the example instead of being anonymous is because `struct node *next` would never be defined otherwise.

Comment: @Qix True... I read Daleisha's answer.

Comment: @Qix Btw, you belie your profile statement ;-)

Comment: I'm back... for now...

Answer (score 0):

For the struct, you are defining your structure name (before the braces) and then the type name (after the braces):

```
 typedef struct node {
   int data;
   struct node* next;
 } node;
```

The next one creates another type, a pointer to nodes:

```
 typedef node* nodepointer;
```

Both can now be used to create variables:

```
 node myNode;
 nodepointer aPtr;
```

Comment: Nope, you can't simplify that struct any more than it already is. You *have* to have the tag on the struct or else `struct node *next` will never be defined.

Comment: Hmm... I think you're right @Qix.  If we didn't have the node* node pointer it would work.  Corrected.